# What's an extensible way of implementing server-side command processing in an MMORPG?

Tags: c#, architecture

**Update: I'm sorry if maybe my question isn't clear enough. I've read about the command pattern, but unfortunately have not used it myself. I'm trying to figure out how I could use it (or some other pattern) to make game events abstract enough that the server can process them using a single Process() method. My main hang up here is making sure the game events receive enough information to actually DO what they need to do (e.g., log in a user and add them to the active user list, send map data, move a player, etc.). A relevant example would be very much appreciated.**

I'm pretty new to game development but have decided to start working on a (relatively) simple, 2D MMORPG in my spare time. I would consider myself to be a very capable programmer and I have a good foundation of skills, but I'm still grappling with some of the design related to a client-server game. Specifically, I'm having a hard time thinking of an extensible way to process commands. Let me provide a functional example:

**Log In Request**

1. Start the game
2. Click "Continue"
3. Type a user name and password
4. Click "Log In"
5. See the character wherever you were when you logged out

From a client-server architecture perspective, here's what I'm doing right now:

**[Client]**

1. Send a **SimpleTextNetworkMessage** to the server - {LogInRequest, UN:[UserName]|PW:[Password]}
2. Darken the UI and wait for a response (timeout: 10 seconds)
3. Receive a **SimpleTextNetworkMessage** from the server - {LogInSuccessResponse, [Player ID]}
4. Send a **SimpleTextNetworkMessage** to the server - {GetPlayerInfoRequest, [Player ID]}
5. Receive a **SimpleDataNetworkMessage** from the server - {GetPlayerInfoResponse, [Player Info]}
6. Send a **SimpleTextNetworkMessage** to the server - {GetMapInfoRequest, [Player ID]}
7. Receive a **SimpleDataNetworkMessage** from the server - {GetMapInfoResponse, [MapData]}
8. Draw the screen

My example identifies three key events that occur:

**Process Log In**

*Validate the information the user provided, download the player information from the database (HP, MP, last location, etc.), and associate the player with a map and a connection.*

**Get Player Info**

*Send back information about the player's stats, equipment, experience, current map ID, and anything else that needs to be displayed on the UI.*

**Get Map Info**

*Send information to the player about all the tiles within a 50 tile radius...this should include tile information for a three-layer map and the locations and names of NPCs/monsters/players; when the player moves, more map information will be requested/updated.*

You can see that each of these processes is different and requires different information. On the server-side, how can I do something like:

```
while (ServerIsRunning)
{
   foreach (Client c in clients)
   {
      eventQueue.AddList(c.ReceiveAll());
   }

   foreach(GameEvent event in eventQueue)
   {
      event.Process();
   }

   int[] keys = messageQueue.Keys;

   foreach (int key in keys)
   {
      Client c = clients.Get(key);

      foreach(NetworkMessage message in messageQueue[key])
      {
         c.Send(message);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: so what's the question? I can't find one in the question text.

Comment: You can see that each of these processes is different and requires different information. On the server-side, how can I do something like:...

Comment: I've read this question three times and it seems interesting, but for the life of me I can't figure out what you're asking. You've posted pseudocode for an event handling loop on the server; what do you want to change about it?

Comment: Yes. It seems like you already have a good plan in place. Simple do what you say you're going to do and it should work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read what you're asking, you seem to be asking for "an extensible way of implementing command processing".

From the way you phrase it, your request obviously points to the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

I'm not a C# person, so sadly I can't do much of a job evaluating the plethora of suggestions Google provides. Here's one to get you started.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cupadhyay/CommandPatternsInCS11142005021734AM/CommandPatternsInCS.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I've read about this pattern already in relation to games, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how the commands will have access to the things they need.

For example, how can a log in command attach the user token to an active user list once the command is successful and put a success message on the send queue? How can a character move request process the move on a map and then send an acknowledgement back to the client? Etc.

Thanks again!

Comment: Again, I'm not a C# person.  I can't build your pony.  I can only offer suggestions from a distance.

If I were trying to figure this out, I'd start with this question: how would I handle it if I were doing hard-coded, compile-time server-side command processing?   

How would you get your user token, your user list, your send queue?